# Tengo dudas sobre esto

Tags: javascript

Tengo este problema, avancé en algo pero no entiendo como seguirlo, si pueden darme una mano o consejos, estaría muy agradecido, no es tarea que no hice y quiero que me la hagan, es un ingreso muy importante para mí y me encantaría aprender con ustedes a hacer.

```
function crearClaseEmpleado() {
  // Crear una clase para construir objetos de tipo Empleado.
  // el constructor debe recibir:
  // nombre (string) , salario (integer) , tareas (array de objetos), jefe (booleano - por defecto false) 

  class Empleado {
    constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe=false) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.salario = salario;
      this.tareas = tareas;
      this.jefe = jefe;
    }
```

Hasta acá estoy seguro que está bien.

```
addTarea(tarea, prioridad) {
  // el metodo addTarea recibe un string tarea y un entero prioridad y debe agregar un objeto:
  // { tarea: tarea, prioridad: prioridad} al arreglo de tareas del empleado.
  // no debe retornar nada.
  
}
```

sobre esto no estoy tan seguro

```
switchJefe() {
  // este método debe switchear el booleano jefe, si estaba en true, dejarlo en false
  // y si estaba en false, dejarlo en true
  // no debe retornar nada.
  this.jefe = !this.jefe;
  
}
getTareas() {
  // Escribe una función que retorne un arreglo con sólo los nombres (tarea) del arreglo de tareas
  // del empleado.
  // this.tareas = [
  //    {tarea: 'compras', prioridad: 1},
  //    {tarea: 'dar clases', prioridad: 3},
  //    {tarea: 'operaciones', prioridad: 2}
  //  ];
  // Ej:
  // persona.getTareas() // retorna ['compras', 'dar clases', 'operaciones']
  this.getTareas[
    {tarea: 'compras', prioridad: 1},
    {tarea: 'dar clases', prioridad: 3},
    {tarea: 'operaciones,', prioridad: 2}
  ];
}
```

Esto no lo entiendo, es confuso, las tareas me las pidió en el punto anterior

```
getTareasPrioritarias(prioridad) {
  // Escribe una función que retorne las tareas con prioridad mayor al entero prioridad
  // ej, si la persona tuviera estas tareas:
  // {
  //   tareas: [{
  //     nombre: 'compras',
  //     prioridad: 4,
  //   }, {
  //     nombre: 'operaciones',
  //     prioridad: 2,
  //   }]
  // }
  // persona.getTareasPrioritarias(3) // retorna 
  // [{
  //  nombre: 'compras',
  //  prioridad: 4,
  // }]
  return this.tareas.filter(t => t.prioridad > prioridad);
}

  };

  return Empleado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso pues simplemente he tratado de recrear lo que entendí de tu problema:

```js
//make the employee class
class Employee {
  //set all properties
  constructor(name = '', salary = 0, tasks = [], isBoss = false) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.tasks = tasks;
    this.isBoss = isBoss;
  }

  //add task to the main array
  addTask(task, priority) {
    const newTask = { task, priority };
    this.tasks.push(newTask);
    return newTask;
  }

  //switch boss status
  switchBoss() {
    this.isBoss = !this.isBoss;
  }

  //get all tasks
  getTasks(priority) {
    //if it doesn't exist, we return all tasks
    if (!priority) return this.tasks;

    //return tasks filtered
    return this.tasks.filter(t => t.priority >= priority);
  }
}

const juan = new Employee('Juan', 345, [], false);
juan.addTask('Hacer la cama', 1);
juan.addTask('Comenzar a trabajar', 3);
console.log(juan.getTasks());
console.log(juan.getTasks(3));
```

Creería que eso es lo que buscas, igualmente, recuerda que ahí estoy guardando las tareas dentro de la misma clase pero en un caso real lo más probable es que quieras modificar eso y guardarlo en un servidor.